# how to add desired propertypages to propertysheet when next button is clicked

Tags: mfc

I Want to add propertypages to my propertysheet .I will let you know my intention i.e,Initially I created a propertysheet and added 4 propertypages . Now in wizard mode as we have Next,Back,Cancel which are used for switching between pages. I want to add different pages when I click on Next button.Moreover I had first propertypage which consists of three buttons where if click first button I must add a page and again if go for second page I must be able to add a page which is different from the previous one.Similarly,when I click on the third button I must add one more different page.I will show the sequence of pages,

FirstPage:

Button1:

Button2:

Button3:

Back Next Cancel

if "Button1" is clicked then Next will be enabled and then click Next then Page2 should be added and again rollback and click button2.

if "Button2" is clicked then Next will be enabled and then click Next then Page3 should be added and again rollback and click button3.

if "Button3" is clicked then Next will be enabled and then click Next then Page4 should be added.

I tried handling it in "virtual LRESULT OnWizardNext()" method ,which returns CPropertyPage::OnWizardNext(). But it is not working fine ,can anyone please let me know where to handle the event such that i must be able to add differnt pages when go for the three different buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any time you can call RemovePage in OnWizardNext and you can call AddPage in on Wizard next.
But you should never remove the page that is currently active (causing the OnWizadNext call).

This code will remove all pages following the current one and you are free to add others. returning 0 lets the wizard to continue to the next page:

```
// Delete all following pages
CMySheet *pSheet = static_cast<CMySheet*>(GetParent());
while (pSheet->GetActiveIndex()<pSheet->GetPageCount()-1)
  pSheet->RemovePage(pSheet->GetPageCount()-1);
if (case1)
  pSheet->AddPagesForCase1();
else if (case2)
  pSheet->AddPagesForCase2();
...
// Do the default and advance to the next page
return 0;
```

Comment: Ok,I got what you said ,but I am bit confused where to add this piece of code in my project,as adding of pages and setting the wizard mode and thereafter calling domodal() in application class InitInstance().As you mentioned to add in OnWizardNext ok that's fine and I got bit confused as I mentioned that I had only 4 pages and the first most page consists of three buttons and this first page also consists of OnWizardNext ,are you adivising me to implement your piece of code in the firstpage OnWizardNext ? So will you please let me know where to implement this piece of code .

Comment: I tried implementing this in my application class InitInstance(),It is crashing while calling setwizardmode() .I made sure that all the pages are derived from CPropertypage.Implementing this piece of code in my first page OnWizardNext would be enough ? and should I stop calling OnWizardNext of the remaining pages i.e,Page2,page3 and page4. Moreover the piece of code you had given is pretty understable ,but didn't get where to implement this piece code .Please have a brief look at this please let me know where to implement this :)

Comment: Nothing is unstable. This code can be used in OnWizardNext of a property sheet. I use this code in a current application vor a dynamic wizard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,finally I got it .